# Find a string in a Excel cell in the fastest way

Tags: python, python-2.x, excel

I have to implement a "filter" in a Excel file which *deletes/shows* particular strings found in specified columns. I save the rows numbers that have to be deleted in a list. I have my filters in several dictionaries containing a list. The column index is mapped to a list containing every string that has to be filtered (in that column, obviously). So I scan every `defaultdict(list)` to populate the `self.row_nums_to_delete` list.

Here's the variables definition snippet:

```
    self.row_nums_to_delete = []
    self.col_filter_delete_strict = defaultdict(list)
    self.col_filter_show_strict = defaultdict(list)
    self.col_filter_show_loose = defaultdict(list)
    self.col_filter_delete_loose = defaultdict(list)
```

Here's how I fill `self.row_nums_to_delete` (I know that this is done **horribly**!!):

```
def populaterownumstodelete(self):
    # checking user selected rows
    if len(self.col_filter_delete_strict) > 0:
        for row in range(1, self.sheet.nrows):
            for col in range(0, self.sheet.ncols):
                if col in self.col_filter_delete_strict and self.parseandgetcellvalue(row, col) in \
                        self.col_filter_delete_strict[col]:
                    self.row_nums_to_delete.append(row)

    # checking strict filter
    if len(self.col_filter_show_strict) > 0:
        for row in range(1, self.sheet.nrows):
            for col in range(0, self.sheet.ncols):
                if col in self.col_filter_show_strict and not self.parseandgetcellvalue(row, col) in \
                        self.col_filter_show_strict[
                            col]:
                    self.row_nums_to_delete.append(row)

    if len(self.col_filter_show_loose) > 0:
        for row in range(1, self.sheet.nrows):
            for col in range(0, self.sheet.ncols):
                if col in self.col_filter_show_loose:
                    for name in self.col_filter_show_loose[col]:
                        if name not in self.parseandgetcellvalue(row, col):
                            self.row_nums_to_delete.append(row)

    if len(self.col_filter_delete_loose) > 0:
        for row in range(1, self.sheet.nrows):
            for col in range(0, self.sheet.ncols):
                if col in self.col_filter_delete_loose:
                    for name in self.col_filter_delete_loose[col]:
                        if name in self.parseandgetcellvalue(row, col):
                            self.row_nums_to_delete.append(row)
```

**EDIT:**

This is how the code is right now:

```
  def populaterownumstodelete(self):
    if self.col_filter_delete_strict:
        for row in range(1, self.sheet.nrows):
            for col in (cols for cols in range(self.sheet.ncols) if
                        cols in self.col_filter_delete_strict and self.parseandgetcellvalue(row, cols) in
                                self.col_filter_delete_strict[cols]):
                self.row_nums_to_delete.append(row)

    if self.col_filter_show_strict:
        for row in range(1, self.sheet.nrows):
            for col in (cols for cols in range(self.sheet.ncols) if
                        cols in self.col_filter_show_strict and not self.parseandgetcellvalue(row, cols) in
                                self.col_filter_show_strict[cols]):
                self.row_nums_to_delete.append(row)

    if self.col_filter_show_loose:
        for row in range(1, self.sheet.nrows):
            for col in (cols for cols in range(self.sheet.ncols) if cols in self.col_filter_show_loose):
                for string in (strings for strings in self.col_filter_show_loose[col] if
                               strings not in self.parseandgetcellvalue(row, col)):
                    self.row_nums_to_delete.append(row)

    if self.col_filter_delete_loose:
        for row in range(1, self.sheet.nrows):
            for col in (cols for cols in range(self.sheet.ncols) if cols in self.col_filter_delete_loose):
                for string in (strings for strings in self.col_filter_delete_loose[col] if
                               strings in self.parseandgetcellvalue(row, col)):
                    self.row_nums_to_delete.append(row)
```

and here's `parseandgetcellvalue()`:

```
    def parseandgetcellvalue(self, row, col):
    cell = self.sheet.cell(row, col)
    cell_value = cell.value
    # checks whether an value may be a int value and converts it (e.g 2.0 -> 2)
    if cell.ctype in (2, 3) and int(cell_value) == cell_value:
        cell_value = int(cell_value)
    return unicode(cell_value)
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here's the code now:

```
    def must_delete(self, value, col):
    if self.col_filter_delete_strict:
        if value in self.col_filter_delete_strict[col]:
            return True
    if self.col_filter_show_strict:
        if value not in self.col_filter_show_strict[col]:
            return True
    # CHECKING LOOSE SEARCH
    if self.col_filter_show_loose or self.col_filter_delete_loose:
        for string in self.col_filter_delete_loose[col]:
            if len(value.lower().split(string.lower())) > 1:
                return True
        for string in self.col_filter_show_loose[col]:
            if len(value.lower().split(string.lower())) == 1:
                return True
    return False

def populaterownumstodelete(self):
    cols_to_check = (set(self.col_filter_delete_strict)
                         .union(self.col_filter_show_strict)
                         .union(self.col_filter_show_loose)
                         .union(self.col_filter_delete_loose)
                         .intersection(range(self.sheet.ncols)))
    for row in range(1, self.sheet.nrows):
        for col in cols_to_check:
            value = self.parseandgetcellvalue(row, col)
            if self.must_delete(value, col):
                self.row_nums_to_delete.append(row)
```

I used the `split()` method to check whether a string is contained in another one since `string in list` didn't work well (sometimes it got single characters and not "strings").

---

By the way, my full application is hosted in this [Github Repo](https://github.com/Krishath/XLS-Polisher) just if someone would like to help me clean my code.

Comment: Why not use Excel's built in filter? Surely it would be more efficient than rolling your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If `parseandgetcellvalue` is an expensive operation, it would be good to organize code so that it is called at most once for each cell.
- Before any looping, you could figure out which columns you need to check. This is easy using set operations.
- If you do all the checks in a single loop over rows and columns, you may be able to avoid some checking because you only need to process each row until you find one reason to delete it.

The above suggest this code for the looping. The actual checking would be in another function `must_delete`.

```
def populaterownumstodelete(self):
    cols_to_check = (set(self.col_filter_delete_strict)
                     .union(self.col_filter_show_strict)
                     .union(self.col_filter_show_loose)
                     .union(self.col_filter_delete_loose)
                     .intersection(range(self.sheet.ncols)))
    for row in range(1, self.sheet.nrows):
        for col in cols_to_check:
            value = self.parseandgetcellvalue(row, col)
            if must_delete(value, col):
                self.row_nums_to_delete.append(row)   
                break
```

Comment: FWIW, `set`'s `union` is variadic. You only need to call it once.

Comment: @Veedrac Yes, good point. I think I'll leave it like it is, though, for readability's sake.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've just edited my question so maybe my code's got better now.